# I want to know, why $Re\Big\{ \frac{zf''(z)}{f'(z)}\Big\}=|z|\frac{\partial}{\partial|z|} Re(log(f'(z)))$

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't know how to prove this, $Re\Big\{ \frac{zf''(z)}{f'(z)}\Big\}=|z|\frac{\partial}{\partial|z|} Re(log(f'(z)))$.
I know it is related whit cauchy riemann equations and partial derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g=u+iv$ be an analytic function with real part $u$ and imaginary part $v$.

We note the operator identity

$$\left(|z|\frac{\partial }{\partial |z|}\right) \lbrace\cdot\rbrace =\left(x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right) \lbrace\cdot\rbrace \tag 1$$

First, we apply $(1)$ to the real part of $g$ and find that

$$\left( |z|\frac{\partial }{\partial |z|}\right) \lbrace \text{Re}\left(g\right)\rbrace =\left(x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right) \lbrace u \rbrace \tag 2$$

Next, we note that

$$\begin{align}
\text{Re}\left(z\frac{dg}{dz}\right)&=\text{Re}\left((x+iy)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)\right) \tag 3\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left((x+iy)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\right) \tag 4\\\\
&=\left(x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right) \lbrace u \rbrace \tag 5
\end{align}$$

where we used the Cauchy-Riemann equations in going from $(3)$ to $(4)$.

Comparing $(2)$ and $(5)$ reveals the coveted identity

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left( |z|\frac{\partial }{\partial |z|}\right) \lbrace \text{Re}\left(g\right)\rbrace =\text{Re}\left(z\frac{dg}{dz}\right)}$$

---

**NOTE:**

For the problem of interest, $g=\log f'$ with $\frac{d}{dz}\log f'=\frac{f''}{f'}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\log(z)=\log(|z|)+i\arg(z)$. Also $\frac{d}{dz}|z|=\frac{z}{|z|}.$ Can you finish it now?

Comment: I would need to know something else, I tryed on that way but I was not able to finish the proof.

Comment: Maybe try looking at $\log(f'(z))$ and apply the chain rule?

Comment: I´ve trying with the chain rule, but I can´t get the right solution.

Comment: I use the chain to derivate log f´(z), and I got this:

Comment: $\frac{\partial log f'(re^{it})}{\partial z}= \frac{f''(re^{it}e^{it})}{f'(re^{it})}+ i\frac{f''(re^{it})re^{it}}{f'(re^{it})}$

Comment: @Monica.Coppo You don't have to complicate things. Let $g=\log f'$ and work with $g$.